# Browser shows hyphen, but there is no hyphen in source code

Tags: css, html

I have a strange behavior, it doesn't matter which browser I try. The output shows me always hyphen, but there is no hyphen in the source code.

[image: hyphen behavior]

How can if fix that? I tried it in Safari, Firefox and Chrome in OSX Mavericks.

You can try it yourself here: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/iJUmEVah/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in Chrome, Firefox, or IE10.

Comment: I don't get this in Firefox for Linux

Comment: I can't reproduce that error. Also the part you are concerned about is not in your JSBIN..

Comment: I changed the JSBIN Link, I can reproduce it on Firefox, Chrome and Safari on Mac OS. @JohnKugelman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the whitespace between "des Gebäudes" including the "G" and starting from "Gebäudes. There is a invisible character there. If it is removed, the hyphen vanishes.

Comment: Thanks thst, I copied the text into Textmate, than I used CMD + SHIFT + 6 and selected "Convert Selection to Entities" this showed me a &shy; between "des Gebäudes". Do you know why this special character is still there after copying to a textmate or Aptana Studio or Sublime Edit? The original Text comes from Indesign.

Comment: The character is U+00AD SOFT HYPHEN, and it is meant to cause effects like this. How it got into the file is a completely separate question, which should be asked with a descriptive title and sufficient details (in some forum – not really on-topic at SO I’m afraid).

Answer (score -1):

It may be caused by automatic word wrapping or word breaking.
Try changing that in css.